# Trouble with video and image backgrounds that can all fit entire screen HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I'm designing a homepage that has a video background that fits the full screen adjusting to size with no whitespaces. Originally my code worked until I added  several images underneath it in their own sections. Now, when the screen size is increased, the video has a whitespace to the right of it and when it's decreased, the images have a whitespace next to them.

I designed the website on canva and this is ideally what I would like it to look like if that helps gain an understanding of what I'm aiming for : [www.specialangelsflowers.com](http://www.specialangelsflowers.com)

HTML

```
<body>
        <header>
            // this is where I have my navbar, left it out due to irrelevancy //
        </header>
        <main>
        <section class="video" id="video">
            <div class="storename">
            <h1>Special Angels Flowers</h1>
            </div>
            <video autoplay muted loop id="homepagevideo">
                <source src="quince.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </section>
        <section class="quince" id="quince">
            <div class="quince-bg">
                <h2>Quinceañeras</h2>
            </div>
        </section>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.homepagevideo video{
  object-fit: fill;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.quince-bg{
  background-image: url("quince.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

full code on my github if that helps too
https://github.com/bananasantana/specialangels

Comment: Please add the images and the video you are using to the GitHub repository

Comment: Just added the images and video to the GitHub repository

Comment: Your style sheet has a rule for the class `.homepagevideo`, but in your HTML it's an `id` not a `class`, so your style rule should be `#homepagevideo` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell your video element that you want it to stretch horizontally to fill its container. Then set its height to be a decent proportion of the viewport height (I chose `60vh` but you might want a higher number). Then set `object-fit: cover` so that the video will automatically be cropped either horizontally or vertically depending on the screen dimensions.

Finally, you can adjust `object-position` to set the focus point towards which the video will be cropped. On my laptop at a height of `60vh` with default position of `center center` (or `50% 50%`), in several of the shots the model’s eyes are being cropped off at the top of the frame. I suggest a vertical position of approximately 25% is optimal for this video.

```
#video video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center 25%;
}
```

Video on laptop at height 60vh with default position:

[image]

Video on laptop at height 60vh with position `center 25%`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use `object-fit:cover;` for video, by this it fills the entire screen. for image sections set `width:100%;` so there is no whitespace appears as the screen size change. also remove `position:fixed;` property from video because with this property there is a big chance that the video overlay on other sections. here is the example:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.video {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#homepagevideo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.quince {
  width: 100%;
}

.quince-bg {
  background-image: url("quince.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```